# jquery change class of a div on click

Tags: jquery

I have a div, with a specific class.

When one clicks the div, I want its class to change to a something else.

Is it because there is no `.class` or `.parent`.

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().class('.mapcollapse');
});
```

Comment: You might want to look at http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'mapcollapse');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One more question, how do I make it a if statement? `if ($("div", this).attr() == "mapexpand")`, is this right?

Comment: @Efe, what do you want to check and what is `this`?

Comment: if statement which will check the class and trigger another event

Comment: @Efe, do you mean something like: `if (this.className == "mapexpand")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'mapcollapse');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('mapcollapse');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
$(this).parent().toggleClass('mapcollapse');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addClass and removeClass functions

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass("mapexpand").addClass("newClass");
});
```

This one removes your current class and adds a new one

Comment: Ohh well was quick, many better solutions posted before me :)

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comments above, here is the correct function.

```
$(".mapexpand").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('class', 'mapcollapse');
    if($(this).type()=="div") {
        // do more stuff
    }
});
```